# Remove 'y' label from plot in R

Tags: r, text, plot

Does anyone know how to extract the 'y' off the y-axis while preserving the variable names in the following plot:

```
par(mar = c(5,7,4,2) +.01)
matrix <- matrix(rnorm(100) ,ncol = 2, nrow =6)
y <- 1:6
par(mar = c(5,7,4,2) +.01)
plot(matrix[,1], y, cex = .8, pch = 20, xlab = "Standardized Mean Differences", col = "darkblue",   main = "Balance Assessment", yaxt = "n")
points(matrix[,2], y, cex = .8, pch = 20, col ="cyan")
abline(v = 0, col = "gray50", lty =2)   
text(y =1:6, par("usr")[1], labels = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Var6"), pos = 2, xpd = TRUE, srt = 0, cex = .8, font = 1, col = "blue")
```

It's minor, but it's driving me crazy. Thanks![image: Plot Below]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just set `ylab=''` to remove it.